# $X_n\stackrel{P}{\to} c$ implies $\mathbb{E}f(X_n){\to} f(c)$ for continuous (but possibly unbounded) $f$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, uniform-integrability

Suppose that $X_n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} c$ as $n\to\infty,$ where $X_n, c$ are all positive. Let $f$ be a continuous (but possibly unbounded) function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $$\int_0^\infty |f(x)|^pdx <\infty$$ for some $p>1.$ Then is it true that $$\mathbb{E}\left(\left|f(X_n)- f(c)\right| \mathbb{1}_{|X_n - c|>\delta}\right)\to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty?$$
The above is immediate for bounded $f$, but note that here we are not imposing that condition.

In case the above conclusion does not hold in general, another question would be: does it hold under the assumption that $\text{Var}(X_n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$?

This issue arose while generalising a proof of Stone-Weierstrass theorem (the usual statement is given for bounded continuous $f$ only). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In these kinds of situations one looks for uniform integrability of $f(X_n)$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought of putting the tag uniform-integrability. Unfortunately, I was unable to finish it.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt whether $f(X_{n})$ is integrable.

Consider the following example: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a
probability space, where $\Omega=(0,1)$, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}((0,1))$,
and $P$ is absolutely continuous with repsect to the Lebesgue measure
$m$ and defined by $dP(\omega)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}}dm(\omega).$
Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}1_{(0,1)}(x)+\frac{1}{x^{2}}1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$
and $p\in(1,2)$, then $f$ is continuous and $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{p}dx<\infty$.
Let $c=\frac{1}{2}.$ For each $n$, define $X_{n}:\Omega\rightarrow(0,\infty)$
by $X_{n}(\omega)=\omega1_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}(\omega)+c1_{[\frac{1}{n},1)}(\omega).$
For each $\delta>0$, $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid|X_{n}(\omega)-c|\geq\delta\}\subseteq(0,\frac{1}{n})$,
so $P\{\omega\in\Omega\mid|X_{n}(\omega)-c|\geq\delta\}\leq P\left((0,\frac{1}{n})\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow0$.
This shows that $X_{n}\rightarrow c$ in probability.

Next, we argue that $f(X_{n})$ is not integrable. Observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int f(X_{n})dP & = & \int_{0}^{1}f(X_{n}(\omega))\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\omega}}dm(\omega)\\
 & \geq & \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}f(\omega)\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\omega}}dm(\omega)\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{2\omega}dm(\omega)\\
 & = & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Nice illustration. Now I am more curious whether the conclusion $\mathbb{E}f(X_n)\to f(c)$ holds if we assume further that $\mathbb{E}X_n = c$ and $\text{Var}(X_n) \to 0.$

Comment: That will give you the uniform integrability condition that make thins work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? I mean, how would we get uniform integrability of $f(X_n)$ from there?